# How to grep -n in a file and save lines between two results into a file

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep

I want to get multiple reg-ex from one file. I made a for loop for that. Each reg-ex has 2 occurrences in the file. I already used grep -n to get the line-number of the two lines in which my reg-ex are located. See example:
`cat ../stdout_info/HTSeqQAllBAMsamples.o277329 | grep -n Sample_10Y_W34` is:

49081:Sample_10Y_W34
73620: sample:  Sample_10Y_W34 is sorted

I wrote the next line to get the regular-expressions. Every 'i' is an reg-ex. (48 i's in total)

```
for i in $(ls ../Datasets_qualityResults/); do echo $(basename $i); done
```

I want to print the lines from 49081 - 736**14** (always minus the last 6 lines) to a file called 'results_Sample_10Y_34.txt'.

I worked on this quite a long time, with sed and grep, but it doesn't work.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: format the description first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correct, you need to say:

```
sed -n '/Sample_10Y_W34/,/Sample_10Y_W34/p' filename | head -n -6 > outputfile
```

The `sed` command would print the lines between the patterns and `head` would remove the last 6 lines of the output and the result would be redirected to the file `outputfile`.